# I wonder why my question was deleted without any reason

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderation

here is my question:

[Resize png image in Delphi - incorrect alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596172/resize-png-image-in-delphi-incorrect-alpha-channel)

I offered a bounty on it, after i didn't get answers, and it seemed, that nobody has the answer on it.

I wonder, what's wrong with the question itself.

Perhaps, it's something i'm missing, but deleting a valid question 6 days after it was asked and with a bounty on it seems exaggerated.

Comment: You have pasted copywrited code that you don't have the copywrite for. Someone flagged the post for that and a moderator acted on that.

Comment: @Oded Seems like a case where a comment on the post would be appropriate then.  At least for questions closed first you have the close reason as a good place to start as to what is wrong with the question.

Comment: @Servy - probably. Or even after deletion (as mods can do that now).

Comment: Indeed. Also, the code was edited and attribution has been added (by someone else). A comment, and link to some related license terms or takedown notice should have been also welcome.

Comment: Can this question be undeleted, in order to be salvaged?

Comment: I undeleted the question. I don't think we should be used to police license terms on code used in questions here. If the author wishes to send a DMCA takedown notice, they can do so to SE proper.

Comment: I agree. I will remove the code, and leave only a reference to the code author and the function name. My mistake.

Comment: This is bordering on madness.  In this case, a user had a question deleted because copyrighted code was put in.  But, on any other day, link-only answers are viewed as poor.  Copyright (in the US) applies the instant someone writes something, whether they explicitly claim it or not.  Therefore, asking people to post code directly in the question here is asking, in general, that they violate copyright low (unless, of course, they ask permission of the author first).

Comment: I think, in this case, i should have been warned(comment) before deleting the question. Since i didn't write a single dot in that code, i see it fair, to remove the code. In such cases, a link only question should be acceptable, if the question contains enough information and original research about the subject.

Comment: I agree with @BradLarson.  My understanding is if SE starts policing questions on their own, then they lose a lot of leverage (and protection) under the DCMA.  I don't think anything should have been deleted without a DCMA takedown notice, regardless of who flagged the post.

Comment: @John It's specified in the ToS that if you're posting code here to the site that you have the right to provide it and also the right to attach the cc-wiki licence to it.  If you don't have the right to post the code, then you are violating the ToS.  If someone doesn't have the right to post code that they have a question about they either need to ask the question without posting code (which is quite hard to do) or they may simple be unable to use this site as a resource.

Comment: My apologies here; I meant to leave a comment, but obviously failed to do so. My hope was just to have the question fixed, as it has been, and to then undelete it.

Comment: Apology accepted. The problem was, that i couldn't edit the question after it was deleted.

Comment: Well; if I'd left a comment for you, it would have provided you with a persistent link you could have used to go to the question and edit it. Or, at very minimum... you would have had a clue why it was deleted! hehe